# Calculating geneology/population given starting population and number of years

Tags: exponentiation, perfect-powers

Is there a formula to figure out how many people could be in a population given a starting population, an amount of time, and an average number of children born per family? I.e. starting with 10,000 people, 2 children per family, and 200 years would result in how many people? How can I figure out a formula for figuring that out?

Comment: What is (in your model) a family? How long do they last, or how are new families created (so that there can be new children)? Some information is missing.

Comment: At what age do they have their children? Do they have their two kids close to one another, or ten years apart?

Comment: Lets say a person lives to be 70 years old, 2 people get together and have 2 babies per family, they have children at the age of 30, and have their kids just a couple of years apart. Lets say two. What other information is needed?

Comment: If every two adults has two children and every child lives to adulthood to have children and things like age distributions and lifetimes and child-bearing age are stable (past and future) then the future population is likely to stay close to $10,000$ people